# How to bind data in ASP.NET MVC 5 / Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm completely new to MVC, moving from Webforms which I know well.

I've got the basics and now trying to work with a database. I can send data to the view no problem but how do I get the edited back?

I'm seeing lots of examples like this:

```
public ActionResult Update(MyObject myObject)
{
    //do database EFW here
}
```

I can't work out how you get the data from the web-form(view) into `myObject`. I'm not doing anything clever I have followed a few examples on line but none explain how this mechanism works.

For the form I'm using `@Html.BeginForm` and helper functions (`Html.TextBoxFor`) etc, to create my form fields. The problem is now I can't get the edited data back so I can update my data. I hit the right controller action.

The only thing that's different is my form a is a partial view inside a bootstrap dialog.

**UPDATE**

Well I finally have a object back in my action method, however it doesn't have the key field populated, only the things on the form so I still can't save it (as an update) because I don't know which one it is.

I get and send this object to the view

`var diary = new mySQLEntities().Diaries.Single(d => d.DRefno == Id);`

and all is good, then what I want to do is this, or something similar

```
    public ActionResult DiaryItemUpdate(mymvc.Diary Diary)
    {           
        mySQLEntities db = new mySQLEntities();

        db.Diaries.Add(Diary);

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

`[Bind(Include = ... )]` doesn't work, it just deletes ALL the properties, even the ones I was getting back.

All the examples I look at seem to do the same thing as I'm doing but it just doesn't work.

I thought this was going to be easy but it isn't. I looked at EF a while back and ditched it for this very reason. It says it makes development easy, it's making it a lot harder for me. I can see why I stuck with web-forms for so long.

Comment: This is exactly explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view). It should help you. Also spend some time on that site to brush-up your MVC skills.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've gotten a little bit further now. See update

Comment: Your question is basically "How do I use MVC and EF?" I don't think you'll find your answer here, this is for specific questions.  There are many different approaches in how to implement MVC, EF and other things.  If you want my personal opinion, this pluralsight guide is long but all encompassing uses best practices and patterns. https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspdotnetcore-efcore-bootstrap-angular-web-app/

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with EF. It's all about [basic model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) which is the heart of MVC. Once you come to understand that you will see the beauty of it and how this really allows you to separate your concerns in a way webforms can't. The [ViewModel pattern](http://stevemichelotti.com/aspnet-mvc-view-model-patterns/) is a big helper when dealing with EF.

Answer (score 0):

Any properties you pass in need to be instantiated in the form if you want them passed back.  You need to add the ID of the object as a hidden form element:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
```

This will ensure that the ID for the object you sent to the view gets posted back.

Comment: Ok thats interesting. I've watched 4/5 videos now and none of them do that. What if I have 10 or 20 hidden values (poor) example ? I'm failing to see atm how EF is any better than doing it myself and ditching EF all together.

Comment: This answer is going to throw OP way off course.  The point of using `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)` is so the Id of the model (as in the object passed to the view) isn't displayed on the page. Any examples you run across would more than likely use a viewModel approach to hide data, that way the data would never even reach the form.

Comment: Adam, the point of using `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)` is indeed so it isn't displayed on the page, but it's also so it's sent back to the controller via the ViewModel which allows you to fetch the actual object from the database with that Id, and update the values.